# Bulk Delete in Dynamics using Web API Java example

Tags: java, webapi

There are various answers provided to bulk delete in Dynamics using C# but not finding any example using Java. We are using OData client to make any calls to Dynamics using Web API and need to implement bulk delete. Any insight or links would be helpful.

Comment: I don't see any Java examples at all

Comment: if you can create the request using Postman you can convert to Java code from there